# Ruby on rails, render 404 when type post id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Post model change to URL parameters to title

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 def to_param
 "#{id}-#{title}"
 end
end
```

When any one type `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/4` it redirect to belong particular post

When any one type post id, How redirect to 404 page?

Comment: Do you mean when has errors show error 404?

Comment: example: when type url _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2-sample-title, it's show exactly page. and any one type _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2 it's show that page. My question is when any one type _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2 how display 404 page

Comment: `def show @post = Post.find(params[:id]) end` this in my post controller

Comment: Post.find is looking for post with id from params[:id]

Comment: what solution for params[:id], how insert #{id}-#{title}"

Comment: You can parse params[:id] like this: `Post.where(id: params[:id].split('-')[0]).where(title: params[:id].split('-')[1]).first!`. But this way is really bad way. Use gem [friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) - that's the best solution.

Comment: If you want to type url _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2-sample-title, described parsing is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could just check if `id` is number or no. And do somehing like that:

```
render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404
```

like:

in application.rb:

```
def check_id(arg)
  if params[arg] && params[arg].match(/\A[0-9]+\z/)
    render_404
    false
  end
end

def render_404
  render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404
end
```

in controller.rb:

```
before_filter -> { check_id(:id) }
```

Comment: example: when type url _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2-sample-title, it's show exactly page. and any one type _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2 it's show that page. My question is when any one type _http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2 how display 404 page

Comment: `def show @post = Post.find(params[:id]) end` this in my post controller

Comment: I think, question is how to raise rails exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound by invalid params[:id]

Comment: if you need `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` execption, you could define your own method for it and just use instead of `find`. In model something like: `def find_by_alias(alias) <check alias as above> end`

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to display a 404 error page from your controller, you can just redirect to your root path like this:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Method to_param needs to build path to resource: apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```

How to make friendly URLs you can find out [there](https://gist.github.com/agnellvj/1209733)

If you want to have user-friendly links, simple way is gem [friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)